# Load custom configuration block from YAML file

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, symfony4, configuration-files

I need to load a custom block from a configuration file located in a custom bundle, I have the following code in my bundle:

```
class ExampleAdminExtension extends Extension {

    /**
     * Loads a specific configuration.
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException When provided tag is not defined in this extension
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container) {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader( $container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config') );
        $loader->load('custom.yaml');
    }
}
```

Then the custom.yaml:

```
parameters:
  allowTraps: 
    - 'Eeeeh?'
    - 'Easy modo??'
    - 'How lame!'
```

This does works, having everything inside `parameters` I can go to a random controller and then print its records with:

```
$trapsAllowed = $this->getParameter('allowTraps');
dump($trapsAllowed);
```

The question here is, when I add a custom block outside `parameters` like this:

```
parameters:
  allowTraps: 
    - 'Eeeeh?'
    - 'Easy modo??'
    - 'How lame!'

items:
  - 'Maruchan'
  - 'How to turn off my chainsaw??'
  - 'Heelppplp'
```

it throws an error that says:

```
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "items". Looked for namespace "items", found none
```

I wish to know how can I achieve this, have a custom configuration block a load it successfully like when I put it inside the `parameters` block.

Comment: To load a block called items requires an ItemsBundle and extension and a configuration tree.  Same answer as your previous questions.

Comment: Okay, my bundle is named ExampleBundle, lets imagine that the```items``` block now is called ```example```, just as the docs says it should be, if I add the configuration tree the outcome doesnt change even a bit, fails the same way with or without it